# admob 6.2.1 nullpointer exception

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, admob

i have a big problem, i want to integrate admob in my android app but i get a nullpointer exception in the graphical layout when i try to integrate admob in the xml file

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.ads.AdView.onMeasure(SourceFile:670)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:542)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:444)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1638)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1389)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1163)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:674)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1730)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

here is the xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundapp"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/add_main_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/add_serie" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/ad_layout" android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="top" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ads:adUnitId="a15086a2a707a22" ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here my class

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    layout.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

thank your for anwsering.

Edit: add an other XML Layout File same Error

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundapp"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_main_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/add_serie" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="541dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    </ListView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    ads:adUnitId="a15086a2a707a22" 
    ads:adSize="BANNER" 
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Edit2:
Problem solved Admob 6.2.1 has a bug for Android 4.1.2 set the Api layout to 10 or lower, have new error messages but doesnt effect the programm or ad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` in `onMeasure` when viewing an `AdView` the graphical layout is a known issue. It will be fixed for the next major release.

In the meantime, editing the raw XML or defining an `AdView` in code works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in the layout design try to code it in the code or just generate the layout and then in the end emplement the google ads xml lines