# Android java.lang.NullPointerException Error

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [admob 6.2.1 nullpointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036188/admob-6-2-1-nullpointer-exception)

This error only shows up if I want to add an Ad banner to my layout.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.ads.AdView.onMeasure(SourceFile:670)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
```

This is my xml file code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGoBack"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO BACK" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRefresh"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:text="REFRESH" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bForward"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="GO FORWARD" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="40dp" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="can't show my publisher id"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

If I remove this code that is responsible for showing the Ads from my xml file, the error disappears.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="can't show my publisher id"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        />
```

I can't fix the error, I hope someone with more experience can point the problem. Thank you!

Comment: How do I add set the Api layout to 10 or lower? As stated in his answer. I want to see if this would fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what that's supposed to mean. You might want to ask him.

Comment: It was asked 6 months ago!

Comment: Less than 3, really, but that's beside the point. If you want to know how *he* fixed it, the best route is to ask *him*.

Comment: Sorry, I missed read it.

Comment: There is no option to leave a comment, only to answer his question.

Comment: The upshot is you cannot use the graphical layout with `AdView`, even setting the API to 10 (pulled down with the Green Android Robot near the upper right), the NPE goes away, but it is traded for a handled expection that still makes the graphical editor useless.

Comment: So if I set the API to 10 the NPE error will go away. Is this what you mean? Right now it is set to plateform 4.2, API level 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem, then i removed the adview layout from xml file and placed a simple linear layout there and attached adview dynamically through code in my activity.It solved the problem.This code can help you-

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);//your linear layout
layout.addView(adView);// Add the adView to it
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```